# determining recurrence relation for number of multiplications of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, recurrence

I have an algorithm

```
R(N)
{
    if(n<=2) return n;
    else
        sum=0;
        for i=1 to n-2
             sum+=(n-1)*R(i)
     return sum;
}
```

I want to get the recurrence for number of multiplications operations performed by R(n).
if

```
T(n)=0 for n<=2
```

what is T(n) for n>2?

In addition, how can I show an exponential lower bound on complexity of M(n)?

Answer (score 1):

1) For n > 2: 
`T(n) = sum(f(i) + 1 for i from 1 to n - 2) =
 n - 2 + sum(f(i) for i from 1 to n - 2)`
  The first equation is correct because
 `R(1), R(2), ..., R(n - 2)`
  are called recursively and than one more multiplication is performed
  after each call.

2)The proof for exponential lower bound:

a) Let's assume that g(i) is such a sequence that:
  `g(0) = 0`
  `g(1) = 1`
  `g(2) = 1`
  `g(3) = 1`
  `g(i) = g(i - 2) + g(i - 3) for i >= 4`
  Then `g(i) <= R(i + 3)` for any valid `i`, because
  a formula for `g(i)` is obtained by removing `n - 2` and `g(1), g(2),...,g(i - 4)` from
  the right side of the recursive formula for `R`(and all terms are non-negative).

b) On the other hand, `g(i) >= f(i / 2)`, where `f(i)` is a Fibonacci sequence
  (here I assume that `f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, f(2) = 1` and so on).
  Proof:
    1) Base case: for `i <= 4` this inequality holds true(one can simply check it).
    2) Induction:
      `g(i) = g(i - 2) + g(i - 3) >= f((i - 2) / 2) + f((i - 3) / 2) >= f(i / 2 - 1) + f(i / 2 - 2) = f(i / 2)`.

c) Thus, `f(i) <= g(i) <= R(i + 3)` so `R` is lower bounded by Fibonacci sequence. And Fibonacci sequence grows exponentially!